# Resume aborted download?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, http, wininet

I have few PC's that run on slow Internet connection network + they use VPNs so the connection becomes really slow.
I have my own app that must download updates from external server via HTTP, but if the update is around few MBs it doesn't get downloaded.
So what i am asking is how to implement download method so i can resume the download if the connection is aborted.

I code on Windows, C++, it would be good if i can achieve this using WinAPI.

I think internet explorer has this feature, so it must be implemented with WININET.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's hundreds of examples of how to download stuff on the net.

Comment: Why are you so keen on using WINAPI when there are decent platform-independent API's that can do this for you (and often are even more easy to use). There's for example the very popular libcurl to begin with.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HTTP resume is somewhat a misnomer as the connection is usually terminated when the download is "paused" and then when it is resumed, a new request is made.

The new request then contains the range specification, so the server only sends a portion of the whole requested file.

Usually you would first fire a HEAD request to get the whole filesize.

**Request**

```
HEAD /big_file.zip HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2000000
Content-Type: application/zip
```

Then you can send a request like this to only download bytes from 1,000,000 to 2,000,000 (if your first download stopped at 1,000,000 bytes):

**Request**

```
GET /big_file.zip HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Range: bytes=1000000,2000000
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.0 206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1000000
Content-Range: bytes 1000000-2000000/2000000
Content-Type: image/jpeg

...
```

That would be the general principle. You can implement it in C++ using cUrl, `boost::asio`, Windows sockets, ... There are many different ways and many good tutorials.

Comment: WinInet also supports this by added the header required header strings.